# LWC - Account related fields should get auto populated in Invoice Object when account is selected

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-wire-adapter

Account lookup in invoice object
[image]

when I select an account in the lookup then that account billing details should auto-populate
[image]

I created a form using lightning-record-edit-form. When I click on account it displays all the recent account records respectively

My Requirement is: Using LWC If I select any account from the account lookup field in the invoice object. Then the account-related fields should get auto-populated in the invoice object fields  I want just those account-related fields to be auto-populated.

please help me with an idea

For the understanding purpose, I asked for Account and Contact, but my objects are Account and Invoice__c
Here's my Apex Controller Code

[image]

and here is my JS

```js
import { LightningElement,api,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import SelectAccount from '@salesforce/apex/NewInvoiceController.SelectAccount';
import accObj from '@salesforce/schema/Account'; //Account Object
import invObj from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c'; // Invoice Object
import accld from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Account__c'; // get AccountId from Invoice obj
import IN_Billing_City from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Billing_City__c'; // get Account Obj Fields
import IN_Billing_Country from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Billing_Country__c'; // get Account Obj Fields
import IN_Billing_State_Province from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Billing_State_Province__c'; //get Account Obj Fields
import IN_Billing_Street from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Billing_Street__c'; // get Account Obj Fields
import IN_Billing_Zip_Postal_Code from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Billing_Zip_Postal_Code__c'; // get Account Obj Fields
import IN_Shipping_City from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Shipping_City__c'; // get Account Obj Fields
import IN_Shipping_Country from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Shipping_Country__c'; // get Account Obj Fields
import IN_Shipping_State_Province from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Shipping_State_Province__c'; //get Account Obj Fields
import IN_Shipping_Street from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Shipping_Street__c'; // get Account Obj Fields
import IN_Shipping_Zip_Postal_Code from '@salesforce/schema/IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c.IN_Shipping_Zip_Postal_Code__c'; //get Account Obj Fields
export default class NewInvoiceController extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {  
    activeSections = ['Info','Address','Dispatch','Amounts','PaymentInfo','T&C'];
   
   @track IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c; 
   

    
    handleAccountSelection(event){
      
            const IN_Account__c = event.detail.value;
            if (!IN_Account__c) {
                this.IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c = undefined;
                return;
             // this.IN_Account__c = event.target.value;
           alert("The selected Accout id is"+this.IN_Account__c);
           alert("The selected invoicd "+this.IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c);
        } 
        
        SelectAccount({ recordId : IN_Account__c, 
                    fields: [   IN_Billing_City, IN_Billing_Country, IN_Billing_State_Province,
                                IN_Billing_Street,IN_Billing_Zip_Postal_Code,IN_Shipping_City,
                                IN_Shipping_Country,IN_Shipping_State_Province,IN_Shipping_Street,
                                IN_Shipping_Zip_Postal_Code,accld
                            ]                 
                 })

                 .then(account => {
                    const BillingCity = getFieldValue(account, IN_Billing_City);
                    const BillingCountry = getFieldValue(account, IN_Billing_Country);
                    const BillingState = getFieldValue(account, IN_Billing_State_Province);
                    const BillingStreet = getFieldValue(account, IN_Billing_Street);
                    const BillingPostalCode = getFieldValue(account, IN_Billing_Zip_Postal_Code);
                    const ShippingCity = getFieldValue(account, IN_Shipping_City);
                    const ShippingCountry = getFieldValue(account, IN_Shipping_Country);
                    const ShippingState = getFieldValue(account, IN_Shipping_State_Province);
                    const ShippingStreet = getFieldValue(account, IN_Shipping_Street);
                    const ShippingPostalCode = getFieldValue(account, IN_Shipping_Zip_Postal_Code);
                    this.IN_Invoice_or_Debit_Note__c = {
                        sObjectType: invObj,
                        IN_Billing_City__c: BillingCity,
                        IN_Billing_Country__c: BillingCountry,
                        IN_Billing_State_Province__c: BillingState,
                        IN_Billing_Street__c: BillingStreet,
                        IN_Billing_Zip_Postal_Code__c: BillingPostalCode,
                        IN_Shipping_City__c: ShippingCity,
                        IN_Shipping_Country__c: ShippingCountry,
                        IN_Shipping_State_Province__c: ShippingState,
                        IN_Shipping_Street__c: ShippingStreet,
                        IN_Shipping_Zip_Postal_Code__c:ShippingPostalCode,
                        IN_Account__c:Id
                    };
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error loading contact',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error'
                        })
                    );
                });
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide your code and point where exactly you have a problem?

Comment: I have added please have a look @PiotrGajek

Comment: It says : AuraEnabled methods do not support return type of System.PageReference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to track the field values in js
example:
@track invoice=invObj;
@track billcity=IN_Billing_City;
and so on for all the fields
and you can use them in on change event(handleAccountSelection) to assign them directly. hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You! It worked